# How to substract two sums of columns from two different joins in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an `articles` table and I want to join two different tables where I track income and outcome articles. I want to substract sum of quantities from one table with sum of quantities from another table. This is what I try but I always get null in quantity.

```
return DB::table('articles')
            ->leftJoin('article_incoming_document', function ($join) use ($warehouse, $warehouseType) {
                $join->on('articles.id', '=', 'article_incoming_document.article_id')
                    ->where('article_incoming_document.warehouse', '=', $warehouse)
                    ->where('article_incoming_document.warehouse_type', '=', $warehouseType);
            })
            ->leftJoin('article_outgoing_document', function ($join) use ($warehouse, $warehouseType) {
                $join->on('articles.id', '=', 'article_outgoing_document.article_id')
                    ->where('article_outgoing_document.warehouse', '=', $warehouse)
                    ->where('article_outgoing_document.warehouse_type', '=', $warehouseType);
            })
            ->select([
                'articles.id',
                'articles.name',
                DB::raw('(SUM(article_incoming_document.quantity) - SUM(article_outgoing_document.quantity)) as quantity'),
            ])
            ->where('quantity', '>', 0)
            ->groupBy('articles.id');
```

Comment: Did you try `->groupBy(['articles.id', 'articles.name']);`?

Comment: Why you think that is a problem?

Comment: List of columns in GROUP BY part should duplicate columns from SELECT part (all except columns that use aggregate functions).

Comment: When I only join incoming documents and sum only quantites from that table everything works perfect but with additional join and substract don't. In first case I group only by id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using multiple joins in query will result in multiple rows for example if one article has 2 rows from incoming table 2 or more related rows from outgoing table which will produce incorrect sum value. To handle such type of issue you can use sub clauses for your related tables (incoming and outgoing) and calculate sum for each article in their respective sub cause. After that join these sub clauses with your article table and subtract their quantity.

In plain SQL it would look like

```
select  a.id,
        a.name,
        coalesce(i.quantity,0) -  coalesce(o.quantity,0) as quantity
from articles as a
left join (
    select article_id,sum(quantity) as quantity
    from article_incoming_document
    where   warehous = :warehouse
        and warehouse_type: warehouse_type
    group by article_id
) i on a.id = i.article_id
left join (
    select article_id,sum(quantity) as quantity
    from article_outgoing_document
    where   warehous = :warehouse
        and warehouse_type: warehouse_type
    group by article_id
) o on a.id = o.article_id
having quantity > 0 // or where (i.quantity - o.quantity) > 0
```

In newer versions of laravel you can use [leftJoinSub](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_leftJoinSub)

```
$articleIncoming = DB::table('article_incoming_document')
                   ->select('article_id', DB::raw('sum(quantity) as quantity'))
                   ->where('warehouse', $warehouse)
                   ->where('warehouse_type', '=', $warehouseType)
                   ->groupBy('article_id');
                   
$articleOutgoing = DB::table('article_outgoing_document')
                   ->select('article_id', DB::raw('sum(quantity) as quantity'))
                   ->where('warehouse', $warehouse)
                   ->where('warehouse_type', '=', $warehouseType)
                   ->groupBy('article_id');
$articles = DB::table('articles as a')
        ->leftJoinSub($articleIncoming, 'i', function ($join) {
            $join->on('a.id', '=', 'i.article_id');
        })
        ->leftJoinSub($articleOutgoing, 'o', function ($join) {
            $join->on('a.id', '=', 'o.article_id');
        })
        //->where('i/o.quantity', '>', 0)  ?? specify quantity of incoming or outgoing, in case of both then add another where clause
        ->select([
            'a.id',
            'a.name',
            DB::raw('coalesce(i.quantity,0) -  coalesce(o.quantity,0) as quantity')
        ])
        //->having('quantity', '>', 0) ?? if you want to perform filter on subtraction of incoming and outgoing quantity then use having clause
        ->get();
```

Additionally I have used [coalesce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) over result of `sum(quantity)` to ignore nulls like

```
coalesce(i.quantity,0) -  coalesce(o.quantity,0) as quantity

DB::raw('coalesce(i.quantity,0) -  coalesce(o.quantity,0) as quantity')
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ba680/30)

Comment: This is not working. There is no result. I try a plain SQL also but it's same result

Comment: @knubbe without viewing any sample data I can't debug your issue, if possible for you can create an online fiddle with your sample data http://sqlfiddle.com/ or https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: Somehow problem is with outgoing document table because that table is empty right now. Also if I remove substract `- o.quantity` it works

Comment: and this is a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ba680/4/0

Comment: @knubbe the problem is with `nulls` as I have mentioned in my answer you use [coalesce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to handle nulls. In [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ba680/28) you can see there are many rows that results sum of quantity with null. Also i have my answer to cater nulls